# What makes lookup table and volatile table different in Machbase?

Tags: database, time-series

From docs, [lookup table has a lower performance](https://machbase.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/MAN/pages/353436419/Lookup+Table) on inserting and updating, while it as well as volatile table stores its data in memory only.

What makes this difference? And what situation is this for?